# Test for absence of an input tag's value attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How can I confirm the absence of a HTML attribute in a Rails RSpec test?

I can verify that an `input` tag has a `value` attribute and that it is an empty string like so:

```
response.should have_tag("input[name=?][value=?]", "user[password]", "")
response.should have_tag("input[name=?][value=?]", "user[password_confirmation]", "")
```

But what I want to do is verify that my input fields do not have a `value` attribute at all (i.e., a blank field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
response.should_not have_tag("input[name=?][value]", "user[password]")
response.should_not have_tag("input[name=?][value]", "user[password_confirmation]")
```

Just use a `value` attribute without the =? part.  So if the `input` tag has a `value` attribute, regardless of what it contains, the test will fail.

Comment: Four months later, I reap the benefits of your research. Thanks, Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous posts on various sites pointing out that have_tag returns an error that there's no such method as has_tag.

My workaround is to use have_selector:

```
    response.should have_selector("input#user_password", :content => "")
```

where user_password is the id attribute of the desired input tag (password field), which I found by looking at the source for my page (in this case, a signup page), and the pound sign delineates that I'm using the id field of the input tag.

I verified that this appears to work by changing the value for :content to "x", and my test failed.

Using 
rspec-rails 2.5.0
rspec 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

how about `response.should_not have_tag("....")`

Comment: How do I specify the lack of the value attribute though?  It should have an input tag, just not a value attribute.